# Content Security Policy with Braintree and Paypal in Safari

Tags: paypal, safari, braintree, content-security-policy

I am using the Braintree Drop-In console, I have just recently come across Content Security Policy issue mainly in Safari browsers where it is returning the following errors and as a result causing client side scripting issues. These errors occur when the PayPal button is clicked, which produces a pop-up window and again once the pop-up window is closed to return the details back to the page.

```
[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "https://checkout.paypal.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://assets.braintreegateway.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

[Error] Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.paypal.com" from accessing a frame with origin "https://assets.braintreegateway.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

I have been advised to enable **enableCORS** in the setup method which had no effect. It is also advised to modify certain directives in the pages policy,however I don't include CSP wihtin my pages so I don't think this will have any effect. 
ie https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/client-reference/javascript/v2/best-practices#using-braintree.js-with-a-content-security-policy

I did try and add some meta tags hwowever it caused more errors than before so I removed them.

Has anyone come across this issue and can suggest or provide an example how to get around this issue? It is only Safari that I am having issues with as it is sensitive to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically these errors within Safari are essentially cosmetic – processing should not be affected.

My issue was due to an jquery ajax timeout issue in safari where I had 
`async` set to `false`. Braintree response was taking more than 10sec in production to return a response and as a result Safari would timeout.

[Failed to load resource: Request timed out on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31140212/failed-to-load-resource-request-timed-out-on-safari)